# Showing that $\varphi: \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \amalg \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \to \mathbb{S}^2$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $$\overline{\mathbb{B}^2} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \|x\| \leq 1\}$$

> Consider the mapping $$\varphi: \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \amalg
>  \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \to \mathbb{S}^2$$ which (informally) maps one
>   $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ to the lower and the other to the upper
>   hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (of course they will overlap on
>    $\mathbb{S}^1$). Now I want to show that this is a quotient map. My
>   question is, how should I approach this task?

First of all, it is somehow clear that $\varphi$ is continuous and surjective. I mean, we could construct a continuous map from $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ to, say, the upper hemisphere. Hence it will be enough to show that $\varphi$ is open. To do so, it should be enough to show that it maps open balls to open balls since the open balls are a basis of any metric topology. But then I struggle,. Do I have to write out $\varphi$ explicitely? I do not see another way.

**Edit.** I think that a possible explicit formula for $\varphi$ is $$\varphi: \begin{cases} \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \to \mathbb{S}^2\\
(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\pm\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})\end{cases}$$ Hence left to show is that $\varphi$ is open.

Comment: Can you recall what $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ is ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am sorry, it means the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for $\varphi$ is correct (assuming the $\pm$ is supposed to become $+$ on one of the $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$s and $-$ on the other).  So, having constructed a continuous surjection $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \amalg \overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \to \mathbb{S}^2$ you are done for free by the following general fact:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space.  Then $f$ is a quotient map.

To prove this, let $Z$ be the set $Y$ equipped with the quotient topology with respect to $f$, so that $f$ is a quotient map when considered as a map $X\to Z$.  By the universal property of the quotient topology (or in other words, the fact that the quotient topology is the finest topology that makes $f$ continuous), the identity map $id:Z\to Y$ is continuous.  But $Z$ is compact, being a continuous image of $X$, and $Y$ is Hausdorff.  Since a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, $id$ is a homeomorphism.  That is, $Y$ has the quotient topology and $f$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Funny, that I just found the lemma in my book. It is known as the closed map lemma. Thanks a lot! +1 I am just struggling a little bit by seeing that $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \amalg \overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ is compact. I mean it should be obvious.

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ is compact, and a finite union of compact sets is compact.

Comment: Yes, I was only a bit irritated by the disjoint union.

Comment: Each of the two subsets "$\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$" of the disjoint union is homeomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ with its usual topology, so they are compact as subspaces of the disjoint union.

Comment: Ah and then you just take the union in the disjoint union space I see. Nice, thanks.

Comment: I will give you the reward anyway, but just to be sure: I tried to figure out how it looks explicitely with open sets. So if $\varphi$ is a quotient map, we would have $U$ open in $\mathbb{S}^2$ if and only if $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ open in the domain. The $\Rightarrow$ direction makes sense but not the $\Leftarrow$ if we equip $\mathbb{S}^2$ with the metric topology. Maybe I am overlooking something. If you like, you can maybe add a short explanation in your answer.

Comment: It may help to remember that a set $A$ has the form $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ iff it is saturated under the equivalence relation: that is, iff $x\in A$ and $y\equiv x$ implies $y\in A$.  So you want to show that if $A\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{B}^2} \amalg\overline{\mathbb{B}^2}$ is saturated and open, then $\varphi(A)$ is open in $S^2$.  Now the key thing is that since $A$ is saturated, if it contains a boundary circle point in one ball it must contain corresponding boundary circle point in the other ball.  And since $A$ is open, it contains a neighborhood of each of the boundary circle points.

Comment: When you take the union of the images of those neighborhoods in $S^2$, you get an entire neighborhood of a point on the equator (you are gluing together "half-neighborhoods" from each hemisphere).